# Is there a way to find out where a Pidyon Peter Chamor will be performed?

Tags: product-recommendation, animals, state-of-israel, peter-chamor

I am planning on being in Israel later this summer, IY"H. I'd like to do a few "unusual" things (call it my "mitzvah bucket list") that I may not do otherwise.

I've never been to a *pidyon peter chamor* (redemption of a first born donkey.) Is there some way that I can find out who. when and where this may be done in Israel? Does anyone publish this online or in an Israeli newspaper or similar?

Comment: If you don't find any other option, there's always https://www.thedonkeysanctuary.org.uk/what-we-do/knowledge-and-advice/for-owners/buying-a-donkey

Comment: There's no way to know in advance when the donkey will give birth or if the kid will survive, and unless you're quite determined you probably won't even know if it's male.

Comment: @DoubleAA I guess you have to live on the farm or be extremely close friends with the farmer. Though, I gather, you don't have to wait 30 days for the donkey, correct?

Comment: @DanF https://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah,_First_Fruits_and_other_Gifts_to_Priests_Outside_the_Sanctuary.12.6 - he can redeem immediately, or he can break its neck after 30 days.

Comment: @DonielF Foolish me - I should have taken advantage of the situation when I was younger and I worked on a kibbutz for a while. My tolerance for sitting around chicken dung is long over.

Comment: App developers- Here's your chance to shine! MyPeterChamorFinder could go for at least $18!

Comment: @JoshK Love it. But, I think MyBriskitch would sell more quickly.